# The class list is giving an error when used with the 'tag' property in main form

Tags: vb.net, list, class, oop, error-handling

So I have created a list called 'menu' in which I have stored all the items' names and prices using a class called 'MenuItem', inside the main form. Then I created a second list called 'items' to store these items in every time the user creates an order with all the items they chose (and then I can use that list to calculate the total etc).

```
Private Sub ButtonClickHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ckburger.checkedchanged, ckwrap.CheckedChanged, ckparmesan.checkedchanged

        Dim menu As New List(Of MenuItem) From
     {
         New MenuItem With {.Name = "Burger", .Cost = 2.0 * txtburger.Text},
         New MenuItem With {.Name = "wrap", .Cost = 2.0 * txtwrap.Text},
         New MenuItem With {.Name = "Parmesan", .Cost = 2.5 * txtparmesan.Text},
```

I then instantiated an object from the 'order' class, where the item from the menu is passed as parameter and stored in a list in one of the methods, and another method is used to calculate the total (which also has the textbox value passed in as parameter so the total can show up on the form). I am using the 'tag' property to read the name of each item and comparing it to the 'menu' list earlier on, to find the item.

So up in the sub I will handle multiple check boxes (for each item) so every time each item gets checked it can be added to the list.

```
Dim button As Button = CType(sender, Button)
        Dim menuItem As MenuItem
        menuItem = menu.Find(Function(item As MenuItem) item.Name = button.Tag)

        Dim order1 As New order
        order1.AddItem(menuItem)
        order1.OrderTotal(txttotal.Text)
```

But when I run the program and check one of the item checkboxes on the form, I get an odd error on the 'menu' list stating 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.' I then tried declaring the list outside the sub, just in the form, but when I run that, I get an error saying 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

(When I tried running the program without the use of the 'tag' property and only using ONE event handler button, I never got this error but instead after the item was stored in the list, when I called the 'orderTotal' method, the total value wouldn't show up in the textbox on the form)

```
Public Sub AddItem(ByVal item As MenuItem)

        Items.Add(item)

    End Sub

    Public Sub OrderTotal(total)

        Dim fullamount As Decimal = 0
        For Each item As MenuItem In Item
            fullamount = fullamount + item.Cost
            total = fullamount
    Next
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and how to sort this, If anyone can help?

Comment: It sounds like you have Project-->Properties-->Compile--> Option strict = On.   If so, you can't set a Double variable equal to a String value.  You must use e.g. `mydouble = CDbl(mystring)`, using the `CDbl()` function to convert the string value to a double.  To test if it's due to Option Strict, turn off Option Strict, and Run to see if the exception (error) is thrown.  But do turn Option Strict back on again, since your code will run faster, won't allow as many coding errors, and is best practice.

Comment: A possible fix is ` fullamount += CDbl(item.Cost1)`.  Also use `value += 1` instead of `value = value +1`, as it's faster.  There's a whole series of e.g. `+=`, `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, etc.

Comment: All this passing thing round using Tag is very odd and totally unnecessary. You'll make your own life a lot easier if you just declare a class level variable that is the correct type, rather than using Tag which is Object and need casting all the time

Comment: *the total value wouldn't show up in the textbox on the form* - your question does not appear to contain any code that assigns the total you have calculated, to anything on the form..

Comment: *as it's faster.* - to type, maybe, because there are fewer characters.. but the rest of your comment is rather nonsensical

Comment: @Hamza you should turn on option infer, option explicit and option strict, and fix all the problems that doing so causes. Those problems appear when you turn on those options because they really are flaws in the code

Comment: @user94325897 right so I checked, and option strict wasn't on initially but I've turned it on now. And now, when I type 'fullamount += CDbl(item.Cost1)' It gives an error saying, "option strict on disallows implicit conversions from 'double' to decimal'. I've also gotten a couple other errors after doing so, which includes the 'string' to double error in the list (same as before), and another one on the parameter 'total' when I try pass the textbox value in the class method, which says 'parameter requires As caluse'.

Comment: @CaiusJard what exactly do you mean by "class level variable", can you please give an example? because I'm basically trying to manage all the checkboxes for the items in the menu on form, so every time the user checks an item it can be added to the list. So I thought the tag property would be best for this? as I can have just one event handler for each of them.

Comment: @CaiusJard regarding the total value not showing up in the textbox, I do have a parameter being passed in the method, for calculating the total = 'MenuTotal', and the parameter IS the textbox value (txttotal.text) in which the total is suppose to show up. So in the code shown, in the method, there is a line where the textbox (stated as 'total') is put equal to the 'fullamount'. So when the amount is calculated it can show up in the textbox. (although it's possible I may have declared this wrong?)

Comment: @user94325897 I don't really understand this string to double error. How do I exactly use "mydouble = CDbl(mystring)", in my list to solve this error? really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please describe in detail what you are trying to don

Comment: @CaiusJard I'm basically programming a restaurant POS system, for which I have made a menu with a range of item the user can choose from. Once the user clicks the 'order' button, all the items chosen are used to calculate the full amount, tax, etc and display it in textboxes in main form. So for this I created the 'menu' list where all the items in the menu get stored, and then as each item is picked, it gets put into another list called 'items' in order class, which can then be used to calculate the amounts.

Comment: But I'm not sure how I could access all the checkboxes so every time one gets checked, I can put it in the list (for which I though the 'tag' property would be useful). And also I have the error showing in the 'menu' list which is about conversion from 'string' to 'double' and 'double' to decimal. So not sure how to get rid of that.

Comment: @CaiusJard Also I have turned on option strict and other options you mentioned. And because of that I'm getting a few errors as well.

Comment: Try `fullamount += CDec(item.Cost1)` for decimal conversion.